# How can microwaves be "concentrated" to create high-temperature plasma?

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-physics, plasma-physics

I have been doing substantial research into the inner workings of the common household microwave lately, because of a recent discovery in Wuhan, China, where researchers somehow ionized air, then lit it to create a high-temperature plasma using a conventional magnetron, whose emissions were somehow "concentrated" using a special wave guide. My question is how one would go about "focusing" these emissions as they did.

The image below illustrates how the experimental thruster is intended to work:[image: This image illustrates how the prototype plasma thruster is intended to work]

Comment: Are you asking about how to focus a beam of EM radiation or how to generate a plasma with microwave radiation?

Comment: Sorry again, I misread your question. I am asking about how to generate plasma using microwave radiation; I should also mention that I recently heard of so-called microwave kilns that use a 1/2" hole drilled into a large cylinder to concentrate the "microwaves," achieving astonishingly high temperatures. I used quotes because to my understanding microwaves typically have a wavelength of ~12.2cm, and wouldn't fit through such a small opening.

Comment: Well you need the microwaves to be absorbed by something like water otherwise they'll just bounce around inside your container.  If you have them absorbed and dump in enough energy, yes you can get to rather high temperatures.

Comment: @honeste_vivere what are your thoughts on the example above, though? It seems like they simply used the radiation to ionize the air. According to them, the ionized gas was ignited with a spark plug that supposedly created a high-temperature plasma that was sufficient to produce thrust. I have seen a recording of the experiment, but it is unclear, based on your explanation, how they achieved this. Thoughts?